# Equivalent of "My Work" in Visual Studio 2013 with Git for source control

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs

The "My Work" feature of Visual Studio 2013 is quite useful when you're frequently switching tasks while using TFS as your source control.

It's not available if you use Git for source control.  Is there a way to mimic it's functionality while using Git for source control?

-Eric

Comment: It's more likely that those of us who are familiar with git can help you if you explain what Visual Studio's "My Work" feature does.

Comment: It saves all your break points and open files and then you start with an empty Visual Studio.  You can have multiple workspaces in My Work for various projects you're working on.  I'm pretty sure this isn't possible to do in git, per se, but possibly with a Visual Studio add in, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such plug-in in VS. But you can achieve the function of code review in 'My work', by using a [pull request](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Code/git/pull-requests) for Git Source Control.

> Please submit your requirement to User Voice site at:
>   http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio